# Nissan Micra 2015 (K13) - Missing front bumper vent

Tags: nissan, parts, bumper

Someone has crashed with my wife's Micra while she was at work, and we have just noticed that the vent is missing, I'm unable to find a replacement online, do I have to get a new bumper?

[image]

Comment: If you are handy with Computer Assisted Drafting (CAD) this would be a fun 3D printing project.  Take the vent from the other side, recreate a mirror image in CAD, then print it out.

Comment: @zipzit haha, that would be cool, but I don't have no time for that :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect the only two places you'll be able to get one of those is either the Nissan Main Dealer or a local breakers yard.

I'd suggest giving your local main dealer a call as you may be surprised by the price.  I personally always try the main dealer first and quite frequently find their prices are competitive.